# Could i use only results without interface with google custom search api?

Tags: google-custom-search

could i use custom search engine without interface in my apps?
I already checked the documents but it doesn't explain about that.
i already asked to help center but no answer yet.
i only need results.
please if you know, help me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes--that's precisely what the Custom Search JSON API is for.

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview